# Spellcheck and Case Insensitivity

Tags: python, oop, debugging, sqlalchemy, spelling

I currently have a working `type` check in `retrieve_user` method.

1. I want to incorporate **case insensitivity** for incoming new user objects and...
2. **check for spelling accuracy** for an entry (`username` of a `user` in this case) -- then throwing up an `Error` message for misspelling debugging.

I think my `NotFoundError` should throw up a flag  when a `username` is spelled incorrectly. It seems as though this is not working since a mispelt username doesn't do anything.

Code:

```
def create_user(self, username, password, firstname, lastname, email):
    new_user = User(username, password, firstname, lastname, email)
    self.session.add(new_user)
    self.session.commit()
    print(username, firstname, lastname) 

def retrieve_user(self, something_unique):
    if isinstance(something_unique, int):
        return self.session.query(User).\
        filter(User.user_id == something_unique).one()
    elif isinstance(something_unique, basestring):
        return self.session.query(User).\
        filter(func.upper((User.username == something_unique))).first() #<DOESNT WORK! results in no entry and no error message
        if NoResultFound:
            raise NotFoundError('No results found')
        elif MultipleResultsFound:
            raise MultipleResultsFound('Too many results found')
    elif isinstance(something_unique, User):
        return something_unique
    else:
        raise ValueError('Value being passed is an object')
```

Question 1 resolved:
    `filter(func.lower(User.username) == func.lower(something_unique)).first()`

Answer (score 2):

Spelling accuracy is a bit harder to check for and can be an  expensive operation. First you would need to implement a metric that represents how close two words are too each other. [Levenshtein distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) is a good option. Now when finding a username fails you will have to calculate the distance from all
 usernames - this can be lowered by only including usernames whose first few characters match as these are less like to be typed incorrectly. Then you can return the closest match as the likely username.

Be warned though, a malicious user could use this feature to find usernames in your system